# Android Build failed (transformClassesWithDesugar) with Visa QRParser-2.2.0 and minSdkVersion 19

Tags: android, gradle, java-8, android-gradle-plugin

I need to parse data from a Visa Payment QRCode with [this](https://developer.visa.com/images2/products/visa_direct/sdk/android/QRParser-2.2.0.zip) library from Visa

But gradle build failed with minSdkVersion < 21 and throw transformClassesWithDesugar bellow

```
16:09:05.083 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:09:05.083 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:09:05.083 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:09:05.083 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForMockDebug'.
```

I tried `./gradlew build --stacktrace --debug`

If I remove the Visa QRParser-2.2.0 dependency it builds fine with minSdkVersion 19 and above. Also, this is a standalone Java library for parsing QR value (not packaging zxling library for QR reading for example. I used Google Vision outside Visa parser for QR reading) so minSdkVersion shouldn't interferes with this dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to add `android.enableD8.desugaring = true` in gradle.properties file.

Thanks to RagnaR on [that gitHub Gradle issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2384)

Answer (score 0):

It is seems like missing some dependency... and it is looks that missong some dependency of sdk. How did you declare the dependency of the sdk? as gradle dependency or as jar/aar local lib?

Comment: Hi, yes, I already added in gradle dependencies
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['QRParser-2.2.0.jar', 'pushpayment-core-sdk-2.0.2.jar'])

Comment: check dependencies of those l8bs an add them(generally it should be noticed in official site or/and documentation. or use gradle dependencies(maven, ivy, etc)

Comment: ok. so you are adding local libs and those libs have dependencies. two way to solve the issue:
1. check on official web site or documentations of the SDKs what are dependencies and add them
2. Check on official site or   documentation if you can add those libs as gradle dependencies

Comment: Hi, thank you for your support : the library is a standalone compiled jar with no depedency. You can check it with the link I provided in the question.

Comment: and what about second lib(pushpayment-core-sdk)? Are you using proguard?

Comment: pushpayment-core-sdk uses zxling but I prefer Google Vision.
I don't use proguard, no. I don't need to minify.

Comment: try to check pushpayment for dependencies

Comment: If it was de dependencie problem, how the hell it could work fine with android API >= 24 ?